# How to integrate ReCAPTCHA into Default Login Form/Comment in WORDPRESS

Tags: php, wordpress, recaptcha

I want to add reCAPTCHA to my wordpress site(Default Login Form and Comment). I search google for this but no affective solution. I'm new in web dev. Appreciate for detailed guide. Thanks so much!

Comment: This below link may helps you.https://codeforgeek.com/2014/12/add-google-recaptcha-wordpress/ .
Or else you can use the wordpress plugin for this.
https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/wordpress/wordpress-security-plugins/wp-recaptcha

Comment: I dont want to use plugin. Use my code as a way to explore wordpress sources.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress have a few hooks that make this very easy. For login you would add something similar to your functions.php file, or create a plugin to easily manage it.

```
add_action('login_form','add_captcha_to_login'); // Login Form Hook
function add_captcha_to_login(){
   //Captcha Display Code
}
add_action('wp_authenticate_user', 'captcha_login_check', 10, 2); // Check Login Hook
function captcha_login_check(){
   //Captcha Check Code
}
```

Wordpress Codex Links

- [Comment Form Hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/comment_form)
- [Comment Check Hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/preprocess_comment)
- [Login Form Hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/login_form)
- [Login Check Hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_authenticate_user)

That should get you on your way to implementing it yourself, but there are plenty of plugins out there to help you do it easier if you wanted.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3  - "reCAPTCHA v3 returns a score (1.0 is very likely a good interaction, 0.0 is very likely a bot). Based on the score, you can take variable action in the context of your site. Every site is different, but below are some examples of how sites use the score. As in the examples below, take action behind the scenes instead of blocking traffic to better protect your site."

Comment: response['score'] receive 0 most of time although I type 'user' and 'pass' by hand. why is that?

Comment: Have you put the correct SECRET_KEY? If you are doing it that way try `wp_remote_post` and try including the ip address as well. https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_post

Comment: I dont know how Google calculates score but I almost got 0. rarely I got 0.9, but it very rare. its difficult to login although user and password are correct

Comment: You need to make sure you are reading the docs. It tells you the answer "As reCAPTCHA v3 doesn't ever interrupt the user flow, you can first run reCAPTCHA without taking action and then decide on thresholds by looking at your traffic in the admin console. By default, you can use a threshold of 0.5."